# Optimizing a Monk/Druid for healing, close combat, and casting (in order)

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, druid, monk, multi-classing

Ability scores: 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8
Race: Human Variant
Feats: 2 bonus
Level: 8
Background: Sailor or hermit
Magic Items: 1 of what could be 1500 gp in value.

Due to my inability to have any sense of what is optimized or not, I am trying to build an optimized Monk/Druid, for the *Tomb of Annihilation* adventure.

The character is basically a castaway that has taken refuge in the jungles of Chult. He now lives in a lost ruin and guards a magic item that brought him to become a "Keeper" of sorts.
He uses wild shape to blend into the jungle and stalk outsiders.
More focused on hand-to-hand than magic.

**My main role in the party is making sure that they live by healing and helping CC in fights.**

Regarding class choices: our DM's homebrew system for character creation was that we rolled for them. I was a life cleric before my character died.  A monk has no healing so I rolled again for a multiclass on a separate table and got Druid.  My PC is currently tasked with keeping the other schmucks alive until BBEG dies, THEN VENGEANCE COMES.

The party I'm joining is;

- scout rogue 6/fighter 2 (party leader/single target dam)(has common sense)
- dream druid 8 (support caster/blaster)(barbs gf/pocket healer)
- Berserker barbarian 6/druid 2 (tank)

Grindhouse rules ToA.

The things I'm looking to optimize are:

1. Healing
2. CC
3. Casting

The main choice is looking to be (Way of Tranquility / Dreams Circle)

My objective is to have an effective character for the above described role for the benefit of both of my friends in the game (DM and Fighter/Rogue).

Comment: (Discussion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83750/discussion-on-question-by-sudsierjet-optimized-class-options-for-monk-druid) and mod responses have been put there.)

Comment: You've indicated most of the details of your character and needs, are you just looking for the optimal selection of 2 feats, background choice, and magic item to achieve the goal of maximizing healing?

Comment: Please take further discussion to the chat SSD started.